# wxPython - Add Image to ListCtrl in any other column except the first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I try to add an image to my ListCtrl, to add it to the first column i pretty easy and was done pretty quick. But i want to have some in other columns. I thought that `SetItemImage` could be my solution but it wont work.

So how do i add images to other column except the first one?

Here is my code so far:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        self.browserList=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(20,20), size=(300,300),style = wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(0, '', width=50)
        self.browserList.InsertColumn(1, 'Column 1', width=200)

        self.list=wx.ImageList(16,16)
        self.browserList.SetImageList(self.list, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)        

        img = wx.Image('Test.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img = wx.Bitmap(img)
        browserimg = self.list.Add(img)

        self.browserList.InsertItem(browserimg, 0)       

        self.browserList.SetItem(0, 1, "First Entry")
        # How to add a Image to it?
        self.browserList.SetItemImage(0, 1, browserimg)        

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I thnk that you will have to use `ultimatelistctrl` https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.html

Comment: Working fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: You can still use wx.ListCtrl, simply use the overloaded method SetItem: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html#wx.ListCtrl.SetItem